# Combine rows of m/d/y & integer for use with charts in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Rails ActiveRecord group_by & sum db results for use with Lazy HighCharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371279/rails-activerecord-group-by-sum-db-results-for-use-with-lazy-highcharts)

I am completely new to RoR/Ruby and i am using Lazy High Charts gem to generate some purdy charts based on some database information.

I have tried the answers that were provided but i am still a bit confused as to how to do this..

I need to sum amount_used, and billed_amount and group by month/year (e.g; Aug/2012)

The end result will be something similar to a dual axis chart with two series "Amount Used", and "Cost".. This information is specific to a certain account_id.

[image]

### Invoices table

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| invoice_date  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| amount_used   | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| billed_amount | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comments      | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### Controller Chart Code

```
@account = Account.find(params[:id])
@invoices = Invoice.where("account_id = #{@account.id}").order("invoice_date DESC")

@h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('area') do |f|
  f.options[:chart][:defaultSeriesType] = "area"
  #Sample dates right now, should be the grouped_by :invoice_date
  f.xAxis( :categories => ['May', 'Jun', 'Jul'] )
  f.yAxis([
    {
      :title => { :text => "Amount Used" }
    },
    {
      :title => { :text => "Cost" },
      :opposite => true
    }
  ])
  #Sample data right now, should be the summed amounts of the :amount_used correpsonding for each above grouped invoice_date
  f.series(:name => "Amount Used", :data => [100,300,500] )
  #Sample data right now, should be the summed amounts of the :billed_amount correpsonding for each above grouped invoice date
  f.series(:name => "Cost", :yAxis => 1, :data => [200,400,600] )
end
```

Comment: Can you show more of the ruby code that you want to add up? Is it database information or a csv or what?

Comment: it is database information.. ill make edits.

Comment: made more changes to the question to include better definition of end result and also the code ive come up with thus far.

Comment: Although I've answered your question for the generic case of "already have the rows", note that any good database will let you make the query for the exact data you want. I don't know ActiveRecord well enough to tell you how to do it, but note that this is the proper way to do it. The SQL you want is something like `SELECT sum(amount) AS total, month(date)+'/'+year(date) AS mmyy FROM invoices GROUP BY mmyy;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to use [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to find all the rows with the same month and then add them together:

```
require 'date'

# Simulate rows from your DB
Row = Struct.new(:date,:amount)
rows = DATA.read.scan(/(\S+) - (\d+)/).map do |date,amount|
    Row.new( Date.strptime(date,'%m/%d/%y'), amount.to_i )
end

sum_by_month = rows.sort_by(&:date).group_by do |row|
    row.date.strftime('%b/%Y')
end.map do |year_and_month,sub_rows|
    [ year_and_month, sub_rows.map(&:amount).inject(:+) ]
end

p sum_by_month
#=> [
#=>   ["Aug/2012", 22000],
#=>   ["Sep/2012", 5000],
#=>   ["Oct/2012", 76000]
#=> ]

__END__
08/01/12 - 10000
08/16/12 - 12000
09/13/12 - 5000
10/12/12 - 76000
```

For your specific use case, you could use this like:

```html
<table><thead><tr><td></td>
  <%sum_by_month.each do |month,total|%>
    <th scope="col"><%=month%></th>
  <%end%>
</thead><tbody>
  <tr><th>Usage:</th>
  <%sum_by_month.each do |month,total|%>
    <td><%=total%></td>
  <%end%></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

---

Alternatively, here's a more direct approach (that I do not recommend):

```
sum_by_month = {}
last_month = nil
total      = nil
@invoices.each do |inv|
  month = inv.date.strftime('%b/%Y')
  unless last_month==month
    sum_by_month[month] = total if last_month
    last_month = month
    total      = 0
  end
  total += inv.amount
end

# Make sure to add in the very last month
sum_by_month[month] = total if last_month
```

Comment: haha you must type way faster than I.

Comment: I like this trick `sub_rows.map(&:amount).inject(:+)`!

Comment: thanks for the code, ill dig into it tomorrow. i ended up going with HighCharts instead of Visualize, this code and the lazy highcharts gem should make this a cinch.

Comment: im still quite confused with this.. I have updated my question with my latest chunk of code. and more descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the additional info. You should be able to group this all and make the table/etc without looping through the records a bunch of times.

```
<% @invoices.group_by { |invoice| DateTime.strptime(invoice.invoice_date.to_s, '%m/%d/%y').strftime('%b/%Y') } do |day, invoices| %>
(@day_headings ||= []) << day  # make an array of your day/year table headings
(@day_counts ||= []) << invoices.sum(&:amount_used) # sum all the invoices amount_used, grouped under this heading
<% end %>
```

...and now that you have your two variables, you can create your table

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <% @day_headings.each do |th| %>
    <th><%= th %></th>
   <% end %>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th scope="row">Usage</th>
   <% @day_counts.each do |td| %>
    <td><%= td %></td>
   <% end %>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the docs for these methods: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html

Comment: +1 for `group_by`. Note that you're using `size` but I believe the OP's actual desire is to sum the amounts from all invoices (not count the number of invoices).