# Rails ActiveRecord group_by & sum db results for use with Lazy HighCharts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I am completely new to RoR/Ruby and i am using Lazy High Charts gem to generate some purdy charts based on some database information.

I have tried the answers that were provided in a previous question but i am still a bit confused as to how to do this..

I need to sum amount_used, and billed_amount and group by month/year (e.g; Aug/2012)

The end result will be something similar to a dual axis chart with two series "Amount Used", and "Cost".. This information is specific to a certain account_id.

[image]

### Invoices table

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| invoice_date  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| amount_used   | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| billed_amount | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comments      | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### Controller Chart Code

```
@account = Account.find(params[:id])
@invoices = Invoice.where("account_id = #{@account.id}").order("invoice_date DESC")

@h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('area') do |f|
  f.options[:chart][:defaultSeriesType] = "area"
  #Sample dates right now, should be the grouped_by :invoice_date
  f.xAxis( :categories => ['May', 'Jun', 'Jul'] )
  f.yAxis([
    {
      :title => { :text => "Amount Used" }
    },
    {
      :title => { :text => "Cost" },
      :opposite => true
    }
  ])
  #Sample data right now, should be the summed amounts of the :amount_used correpsonding for each above grouped invoice_date
  f.series(:name => "Amount Used", :data => [100,300,500] )
  #Sample data right now, should be the summed amounts of the :billed_amount correpsonding for each above grouped invoice date
  f.series(:name => "Cost", :yAxis => 1, :data => [200,400,600] )
end
```

Comment: what are you looking for exactly as answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you have everything in place. Here's how you can pull data from db:

```
@aggregated_invoices = Invoice.
  where(:account_id => params[:id]).
  order("invoice_date DESC").
  group("invoice_date").
  select("DATE_FORMAT(invoice_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS invoice_date, sum(amount_used) AS amount_used, sum(billed_amount) AS billed_amount")

# Then use these instead of sample data:
@categories = @aggregated_invoices.map {|i| i.invoice_date.strftime("%b/%Y")}
@amount_used_data = @aggregated_invoices.map(&:amount_used)
@billed_amount_data = @aggregated_invoices.map(&:billed_amount)
```

Comment: you my friend are a god send!

Comment: its not showing the proper months across the bottom as month/year (shows integers counting from 0-43) Could this be because the invoice_date column is a text field and not in a standard datetime format?

Comment: yeah, let me update answer with date formatting... btw, do you want just 'May' or 'May 2012' in your categories?

Comment: May/2012, i am changing the column to the standard mysql datetime col type as it should be that by standards purposes.

Comment: if `invoice_date` becomes `datetime`, than my last edit may work: ActiveRecord will cast `invoice_date` based on column type, hence `strftime` should be available.

Comment: got it working with your code. Now i just need to figure how to get HighCharts to span month on a seperate line from year..

Comment: HighCharts allows `<br>` in some places. Unless LazyHighCharts does escaping of its own, I'd try `strftime("%b<br/>%Y")`

Comment: i got it working by changing my categories highchart definition to this `f.xAxis( :categories => @categories, :labels => { :rotation => -45, :align => 'right' } )`

Comment: i also modified the query to include only the past 24 months.. `where("invoice_date >= now() - interval 24 month").`

Comment: Good job showing how to let the DB perform the grouping and summing.